# disable cache in kubernetes Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

in kubernetes V 1.14.5   with ingress controller nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0-rancher3 .I have below issue:

when userinfo api is called with internal service address (form inside cluster), it response fine (token is invalid). as below screenshot

[image: ((]
but when that API is called with its ingress name, it responses with list of permission while token is revoked. both requests use same tokens

[image]

I think its related to cache inside Ingress and Ingress Controller but I cant disable it vi annotation configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Nginx ingress controller you can use this snippet into the annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet : |
      if ($request_uri ~* \.(js|css|gif|jpe?g|png)) {
        expires 1M;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }
```

inside the configuration, you can keep the simple **Nginx** config

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

the root cause was related to wso2is  nginx mosuled, and cache was configured there. I change cache time in nginx configuration inside wso2is